# Execute .BAt file as admin

Tags: cmd, wifi, admin, lan, disabled-control

I am trying to execute this command which allows me to switch between Lan line and wireless.

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh interface set interface name="Ethernet" admin=DISABLED
```

I have tried.

```
runas /user:administrator C:\Windows\system32>netsh interface set interface name="Ethernet" admin=DISABLED
```

when I execute it using notepad as double click, nothing happens, but when I go to cmd, execute CMD as ADMIN and copy and paste.

```
netsh interface set interface name="Ethernet" admin=DISABLED
```

then Lan gets disabled,

I want to double click the notepad(.BAT) file and want it to execute but something is not allowing it to execute. any ideas?

Comment: Right click > run as administrator.

Comment: i get a pop up to run as admin, when click yes, unfortunately nothing happens after that. LAN stays able doesnt disables off.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is a `.bat` ( Are you sure it isn't a `.txt`? ) you have to:

`right click` on the file and then >

```
Run as administrator
```

If you arent sure if the file is a `.bat` you should either check from the icon or create a brand new one by

Opening notepad, paste the code, save as, delete all the file name and write:

```
filename.bat
```

Comment: created a new file, with code in it  C:\Windows\system32>netsh interface set interface name="Ethernet" admin=DISABLED"   saved the file as .bat   .. it shows as gears as before as well  .. then i right clicked on the bat file , run as admin, nothinn happens.